# How to change file extensions of existing files simultaneously

Tags: windows-10, rename, file-extension

Is there a way to change the file extensions of existing files (inside a folder) simultaneously?

I have a folder and within are different subfolders (nested). All the files are .txt, and I want to change them all to .md.

Is there a way to change those simultaneously, or do I really need to modify them one by one? :-(

Thanks,
Faye

Additional questions:

@user1016274 : Thanks. By the way, will it also work with files with no extensions? I haven't tried it yet, but I discovered just now that some folders have files with no extension. Pls see the image I added (above), pls see it. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrEJD.png)

Comment: Run `cmd`, go to the directory where the files reside, and type `ren *.txt *.md`.

Comment: @AFH : Thanks for the reply, but that solution won't be good in my case, because I have multiple deeply nested folder structure. Doing that would mean I have to do it in every single folder, every single subfolder, every folder inside all subfolders, etc. Is there any other solution? Thanks, Faye..

Comment: If I'd been at my computer when you responded, I'd have given you [user1016274](https://superuser.com/users/438316/user1016274)'s answer. Note that `ren` and `rename` are synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rename` command allows for a wildcard:
`rename *.txt *.md` would rename all files in one call, in the current directory.

Now you just need to traverse all directories down from the root dir. For this, there is a `for` command:
`cd /d <rootdir> & for /R %d in (.) do @echo %d`

Putting it all together:

```
cd /d <rootdir>
for /R %d in (.) do @rename "%d\*.txt" *.md
```

Comment: Can you pls make it a bit clearer to me. Do I need to type that 'as is', and I just need to change the <rootdir> and put my directory name, ie ie: <E:\Documents\Freelance\Project22\> ? Thanks, Faye

Comment: Yes, exactly. To be safe, you could make a test run with `do @dir /b %d\*.txt`. You will see an error message for each directory which does not contain any '.txt' file.

Comment: Thanks, I will experiment with that later at home, and will mark this as correct answer if I got it right. Thanks.

Comment: Please note: I added quotation marks to take care of directories containing spaces in their names. And secondly, the syntax is correct for running the command from a command line, not within a batch file. Within a batch file, you need to double each '%' character.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, will it also work with files with no extensions? I haven't tried it yet, but I discovered just now that some folders have files with no extension. Pls see the image I added (above), pls see it. Thanks. Those are also text files (book stories), I can view them and edit them in VS-Code, but they have no extensions.

Comment: Yes, leaving out the extension would rename all and every file: `rename "%d\*" *.md`.